# Replace hidden text with correct information on click

Tags: jquery

I'm creating an online resume and want to hide part of my personal details until the user clicks a button to show it. I'm hoping this will prevent spammer's from being able to get my personal details as easily.

The concept is basically what [gumtree.com.au](http://www.gumtree.com.au) do, which can be seen in the image below for those outside of Australia:

[image: Gumtree]

My page's HTML is:

```
<div class="personal">
    <p>042323**** <span id="phone">show number</span></p>
</div>
```

And I was planning on using jQuery to remove the asterisks, then add the last 4 digits of my number (which I was going to just hardcode into the JavaScript file).

Firstly, would this be the best way to go about doing something like this? If so, how can I remove the asterisks and replace them with the correct details using jQuery?

Comment: You can just do something with `replace('****','1234')` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your number in a tag like this -

`<p><span id='number'>042323****</span> <span id="phone">show number</span></p>`

and then you can do this -

```
var num = 1234; // hard-coded number - last 4 digits
$('#phone').on('click',function(){
    $('#number').text(function(_,txt){
        return txt.replace('****',num);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

`HTML`

```
<div class="personal">
   <p>042323**** </p><span pno="0423231212" id="phone">show number</span>
</div>
```

Store your original number in pno attribute and then write this jQuery code to show it on show number click.

`jQuery`

```
jQuery("#phone").click(function() {
    jQuery(".personal").find("p").html(jQuery(this).attr("pno"));
});
```

You can have animation also while showing your number on click. There are various methods available in jQuery.

Refer this for animation functions for various effects - http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

`jQuery example for fade animation`

```
jQuery("#phone").click(function() {
    jQuery(".personal").find("p").html(jQuery(this).attr("pno")).hide().fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

changed html:

```
<div class="personal">
    <p><span id="personal-phone-number">042323****</span><span id="phone">show number</span></p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#phone').click(function(){
         $('#personal-phone-number').html('0438866666');
         $(this).hide();
       });
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple method would be to replace the whole number with the full one

```
$('#phone').closest('p').html('0438866666');
```

Comment: Than you would have something like `<p>042323**** <span id="phone">0438866666</span></p>`.